# How can I change the date format in multiple divs using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date, replace

I am pulling an `RSS feed` onto my site which contains a date in the format `dd/mm/yyyy (UK date format)`. The dates are wrapped in `h3 tags`, I would like to replace the original date with 2 divs containing only the date and the month respectively. I've managed to achieve this but the date outputted is the same for every instance.

How can I replace the date in each respective div? I've tried all sorts but I can't quite figure it out. No doubt there is a far simpler way to do it! Any help is greatly appreciated.

The HTML is:

```
<div class='news'>
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <h3>11/06/2013</h3>
    <p>Content</p>
</div>
<div class='news'>
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <h3>07/06/2013</h3>
    <p>Content</p>
</div>
```

And the javascript is:

```
var monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May",
    "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"
]; // Define month names array

$(".news h3").each(function () {
    // Gets date and puts it in variable 'postDate'
    var postDate = $(this).html();
    // Reformats date into UK format after Javascript date object is created
    var d = new Date(postDate.split('/')[2], postDate.split('/')[1] - 1, postDate.split('/')[0]);

    $('.news h3').replaceWith('<div class="blogDate">' + d.getDate() +
        '</div><div class="blogMonth">' + monthNames[d.getMonth()] +
        '</div>'); //Replaces original date with newly created divs

});
```

I've created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XRmHu/1/) so you can see the output . The bottom date should read `7 Jun`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to replace the content of the current `h3` instead of replacing all

```
$(this).replaceWith('<div id="blogDate">' + d.getDate() + '</div><div id="blogMonth">' + monthNames[d.getMonth()] + '</div>');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/eRhT7/1/)

More correct fix

```
$(".news h3").replaceWith(function(){
    var postDate = $(this).html();
    var parts = postDate.split('/');

    var d = new Date(parts[2], parts[1] - 1, parts[0]);

    return '<div id="blogDate">' + d.getDate() + '</div><div id="blogMonth">' + monthNames[d.getMonth()] + '</div>';
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/eRhT7/3/)

If you can include a date-time library [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) then

```
$(".news h3").replaceWith(function(){
    var text = moment($.trim($(this).text()), "DD/MM/yyyy").format('D MMM');
    return '<div>' + text + '</div>';
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/eRhT7/4/)

Comment: Wow, I think you win the award for fastest response! Thanks a lot, it works perfectly. Now to try and figure out what's going on!